# what is a shorter phrase of "a shelter for collecting outcome"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

What is a shorter phrase for "a shelter that collects outcome"?

Comment: What does "collects outcome" mean? What outcomes are you collecting?

Comment: Do you have a picture of such a shelter? Perhaps the phrase is a literal translation; if so, it can help to say something like "In Dutch, we call this a ..." but a picture speaks a thousand words.

Comment: @Dan Bron  It's a shelter for collecting the outcomes of oil palm fresh fruit bunches.

Comment: So like a little shed to house the bananas or whatever you're harvesting from the trees?

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's a shelter for collecting the outcomes of oil palm fresh fruit bunches, but I am expecting a shorter phrase for it.

Comment: The reason we're having difficulty is that *outcome* is almost certainly not the right word here.

Comment: @AndrewLeach She means the produce, the fruit of the trees.  There's some kind of shed or something where the fruit are temporarily housed after harvesting, before they're sent off to market or processing or whatever.

Comment: the fresh fruit bunches are collected (in a plantation), then transported to this aforementioned _shelter_ **before they are brought to the factories.**

Comment: Another question, sorry - Shelter from what? Rain (just a roof), wind (just a couple of walls), heat (requiring shade and insulation)? Or something else?

Comment: *Storage Warehouse*

Comment: +1, Or possibly just *Store*. Temporary store?

Comment: @Rathony All the research I've been able to do indicates that palm oil fruit bunches ("fresh fruit bunches", which they call "FFBs") are processed as quickly as possible, ideally within 24 hrs, to prevent the buildup of fatty acids in the resulting oil. So they're not being "warehoused" - I honestly can't even find a photo of one of these shelters.

Comment: @DanBron I don't think a storage warehouse necessarily means you need to store anything for more than a day. Some products can come in and go out within an hour if there are exploding orders or some storage issues like you mentioned.

Comment: May, this question is very unclear. Can you edit it to provide more detail? what is being collected (outcome is not right), and what does this 'shelter' look like?

Comment: [*Fruit warehouse*](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Fruit+Warehouse) does exist.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about a *harvest* of fresh-cut oil-palm fruit ...

[image: Oil palm fruit]

and a structure rather like this (though perhaps with more walls)...

[image: Dutch barn]

then it's called a ***barn.***

---

Images via Wikimedia Commons; barn by Stanley Howe.

Answer (score 1):

[**Platform**](http://www.tojsat.net/index.php/tojsat/article/viewFile/203/196):

> In history of harvesting oil palm FFB, FFB and loose fruit will be loaded in
>   wheelbarrow the number 2-4 of FFB, will be wheeled through the path of tree harvesting in the number of 10-15
>   trees up to the platform. From the platform of FFB will be sent to the factory for processing

from The Online Journal of Science and Technology, April 2015 (page 46)

(Although to me, this sounds auto-translated so treat with caution)